# How to persist a reducer so I can find a unique object from it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am building the ability for a user to cancel a scheduled notification. Each notification has a unique id that I need to find in order to cancel it. They are stored in my reminders reducer in a piece of state called notificationIDs along with two other properties to uniquely identify the object.

When the user tries to cancel the notification I find the notificationID with the unique identifiers. This is where the problems begin. Sometimes the notificationID is there, sometimes it's not. Even though I see the object I am looking for in the piece of state when I look for it, it returns undefined. The piece of state also randomly deletes itself and goes back to nothing instead of continuing to persist.

I am unsure if the issue is in the persistance of the reducer or my reducer itself, my hunch is it is a combination of both.

My redux store:

```
const remindersPersistConfig = {
  key: 'remindersreducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['notificationIDs'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['TodoReducer', 'RemindersReducer'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  ModalReducer,
  TodoReducer: persistReducer(todoPersistConfig, TodoReducer),
  RemindersReducer: persistReducer(remindersPersistConfig, RemindersReducer),
  AuthReducer
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, reducers);

export default function storeConfiguration() {
  const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    {},
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    )
  );

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
}
```

My add and cancel notification actions:

```
export const addNotifiactionID = (item, reminderType, notificationID) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID,
    notificationID,
    item,
    reminderType
  };
};

export const cancelNotification = (item, reminderType) => {
  return {
    type: CANCEL_NOTIFICATION,
    id: item.id,
    reminderType
  };
};
```

The reducer in charge of taking the info and finding the notificationID:

```
const initialState = {
  notificationIDs: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PERSIST_REHYDRATE:
      return action.payload.RemindersReducer || [];
    case ADD_NOTIFICATION_ID:
      return { ...state,
        notificationIDs: [...state.notificationIDs,
        {
          itemID: action.item.id,
          reminderType: action.reminderType,
          notificationID: action.notificationID
        }]
      };
    case CANCEL_NOTIFICATION: {
      console.log(state.notificationIDs);
      const notificationData = state.notificationIDs.find(
        item => (item.itemID === action.id && item.reminderType === action.reminderType)
      ); //issue is redux notificationIDs randomly dissapear from reducer
      console.log(notificationData);
      //Notifications.cancelScheduledNotificationAsync(notificationData.notificationID);
      return;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My console logs show the reminder being there and then notificationData returning undefined sometimes, sometimes it will work the way it should, and sometimes there is nothing in notificationIDs even though I don't delete the state anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your CANCEL_NOTIFICATION reducer you are not returning any state. Could probably be the cause of data missing.

```
case CANCEL_NOTIFICATION: {
      console.log(state.notificationIDs);
      const notificationData = state.notificationIDs.find(
        item => (item.itemID === action.id && item.reminderType === action.reminderType)
      ); //issue is redux notificationIDs randomly dissapear from reducer
      console.log(notificationData);
      //Notifications.cancelScheduledNotificationAsync(notificationData.notificationID);
      return; //<-- you are not returning a state here
    }
```

Comment: I did this and while it helped the data deleting it didn't solve the issue of the reminders canceling.

Comment: What seems to be happening is when I cancel the notification the state that was added during the same session gets deleted and then it returns undefined. What I have noticed though is it works if I add the notification, reload the app, and then cancel it. There is some issue with the state updating during the session that is causing this I guess. Any Ideas?